# Помогите с if`ом, обрабатываещем пустой чекбокс. Если чекбокс пустой, показывай все содержимое таблицы, если нет-определенные записи

Tags: c#

```
var t = db.Person.Where(c => c.Sirname == txtSearch.Text).Select(x => new
{
    Фамилия = x.Sirname,
    Имя = x.Name,
    Отчество = x.Secname
}).ToList();

grid.DataSource = t;
grid.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

Огромное достоинство технологии LINQ - лёгкая композиция запросов. В зависимости от каких-либо условий можно добавлять фильтрацию, проекцию и прочее.

В частности, по вашему вопросу, добавим в запрос фильтрацию. Для этого разобьём запрос на части. Не стоит боятся ухудшения производительности или чего-либо ещё: sql-запрос будет сгенерирован по всему конечному выражению.

```
var t = db.Person.Where(c => c.Sirname == txtSearch.Text);

if (checkBox.Checked)
    t = t.Where(/* условие */);

var list = t.Select(x => new
    {
        Фамилия = x.Sirname,
        Имя = x.Name,
        Отчество = x.Secname
    }).ToList();
```

Далее используете `list`.

---

Возможно, вам нужно самое первое условие исключить или включить в зависимости от чекбокса. Такой код не скомпилируется:

```
var t = db.Person;

if (checkBox.Checked)
    t = t.Where(c => c.Sirname == txtSearch.Text);
```

Потому что в данном случае `t` будет иметь тип `DbSet<TEntity>`. Исправим код следующим образом, вручную задав нужный тип:

```
IQueryable<Person> t = db.Person;

if (checkBox.Checked)
    t = t.Where(c => c.Sirname == txtSearch.Text);
```

Далее добавляете `Select` и любые другие методы.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.